# how to limit the number of documents by different field value in solr

Tags: solr, full-text-search

My doc in schema.xml is like:

`...
<field name="type" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
...`

I want to limit 10 docs(when theirs type = 1) in results

In other words, when i request with pagesize=30. There are at most 10 docs with type=1 in results, and others are type = 2

Answer (score 0):

You can perform **grouping** on that field(int). Below is the description from Solr documentation.

#### Result Grouping

> Result Grouping groups documents with a common field
>   value into groups and returns the top documents for each group. For
>   example, if you searched for "DVD" on an electronic retailer's
>   e-commerce site, you might be returned three categories such as "TV
>   and Video," "Movies," and "Computers," with three results per category

To limit the result from each group, like in your case you want only 10 results from type 1. You can use **group.limit**

#### Group Limit

> Specifies the number of results to return for each group. The default
>   value is 1.

Comment: I know that, But I want to remix them. `group.limt` can not assign a special group, it's globe setting. for example, when pagesize=30, I want to get at most 10 docs with type=1 and at least 20 with type = 2. I am thinking about `fq` Query, But I don't know how to limit.